# Changing the WPF DatePicker Year/Month header area background color

Tags: wpf

How can i change the background color of the header section of the WPF toolkit datepicker control? 
Since the Default color is dark blue and the foreground is in black, it seems a bit difficult to read the text.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

just see this link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882520.aspx

the code can be download from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mag200906Foundations

hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the default template of the datepicker control using Blend.
Just needed to change the style to the appropriate color and set the datepicker's Calander style to it.

Answer (score 0):

This color is set with the CalendarBGBrush in the first Grid inside the CalendarItem template. The brush is a gradient with a hard stop at the top. This is where the blue color is. You'll have to make your own template for the calendar and then you can replace or adjust this brush.