# system.windows.datepicker change header background color

Tags: wpf, datepicker, styles

I have been trying to change the background color of wpf's default datepicker. Right now it is dark blue with black text and client wants it changed to white. I have been coding a lot and nothing seems to work.

Pls help. thanks

```
 <Style x:Key="DateStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DatePcker}" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="CharacterCasing" Value="Upper"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
</Style>
```

here's my datepicker

```
 <DatePicker Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="4" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TabIndex="3" 
                                                        Name="dpFillingDateFrom" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="97" Text="12/12/2011" SelectedDateFormat="Short"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3185305/577167

Answer (score 0):

Just go through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882520.aspx.
Its not straight forward to change the background color of wpf's default datepicker but you can follow below steps

1) Date picker has a CalenderStye Property so override Calender Default ControlTemplate

2) In Calender control template, there is CalenderItemStyle where you can override CalenderItemStyle defaulttemplate. In this you can customize the background colors as well as header buttons.

```
<Style x:Key="ItemStyle" TargetType="primitives:CalendarItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>

            <ControlTemplate TargetType="primitives:CalendarItem">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="DayTitleTemplate">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                <DockPanel Name="PART_Root" 
                                   LastChildFill="True">
                    <Button x:Name="PART_PreviousButton" 
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                    Content="&lt;"
                                    Focusable="False" />

                    <Button x:Name="PART_NextButton" 
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                    Content="&gt;" 
                                    Focusable="False" />

                    <Button x:Name="PART_HeaderButton"                                             
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                    FontWeight="Bold"
                                    Focusable="False" />

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_MonthView" 
                                      Visibility="Visible">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid x:Name="PART_YearView" 
                                      Visibility="Hidden">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/> 
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="PART_DisabledVisual" Opacity="0" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="#A5FFFFFF"/>
                </DockPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_DisabledVisual" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type toolkit:Calendar}}, Path=DisplayMode}" Value="Year">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_MonthView" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_YearView" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type toolkit:Calendar}}, Path=DisplayMode}" Value="Decade">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_MonthView" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_YearView" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="pp" TargetType="toolkit:Calendar">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:Calendar">
                            <StackPanel Name="PART_Root" 
                Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <primitives:CalendarItem 
            Name="PART_CalendarItem" 
            Style="{StaticResource ItemStyle}"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Margin="4 4 0 4">
                                    <ScrollViewer 
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    Height="{Binding ElementName=PART_CalendarItem,
                                     Path=ActualHeight}"
                    Width="100">
                                        <ItemsControl 
                    ItemsSource=
                        "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                      AncestorType=toolkit:Calendar}, 
                                  Path=SelectedDates}" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Border>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <toolkit:DatePicker CalendarStyle="{StaticResource pp}" Margin="0,0,0,242"></toolkit:DatePicker>
```

Comment: this is working(the look of cal changed) but I can't get to change only the header. i just want the header color be changed. I can't figure out what to do with the xaml, i tried experimenting and I end up with weird looking cal. pls note that I don't have toolkit

Comment: I was able to change the header now but now I can't change the hi light color of selected date. May I ask under what property / tag is the selected date ?